# Swift: Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[__NSCFSet getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1375886c0

Tags: swift

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[__NSCFSet getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1375886c0

0 CoreFoundation    __exceptionPreprocess

3 CoreFoundation    ___forwarding___

4 CoreFoundation    _CF_forwarding_prep_0

5 CoreFoundation    CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy

29 libsystem_pthread.dylib  start_wqthread
```

Found this crash in Crashlytics. cannot find the line where it is crashing and the reason. plz help..

Comment: Try to check if this is a required function that you must implement at your delegate

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that crash lyrics provides too

Comment: @Warren i have edited the post with stack trace

Answer (score 0):

- find all location of function **getObjects:... andKeys:...**, I think enough for just find of getObjects:
- check for all targets of that targets of finds. print(**result thing**)
- some of var is must be Set type when it expecting be NSDictionary.

I doubt that you have casting to dictionary from any type for some results   without any of checking variable type.